# HBox doesn't fill the available space in center of borderpane

Tags: java, javafx

I placed an `HBox` into the center of a `BorderPane`, that is the only direct `Node` on a `DialogPane` of my `Dialog` by using this code:

```
    public GameDialog(Player[] players) {
          setTitle("Spiel eintragen");
          setWidth(WIDTH);
          setHeight(HEIGHT);

          createLeftBox();
          createRightBox(players);

          // Center
          this.center = new HBox(leftBox, rightBox);
          center.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #00ff00;");
          center.getChildren()
                .forEach(b -> HBox.setMargin(b, INSETS));

          // Bottom
          this.btnOk = new Button("ok");
          this.btnCancel = new Button("abbrechen");
          this.bottom = new HBox(btnOk, btnCancel);
          bottom.getChildren()
                .forEach(b -> HBox.setMargin(b, INSETS));

          // Pane
          this.pane = new BorderPane(center);
          pane.setBottom(bottom);
          pane.setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
          getDialogPane().setPrefSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
          getDialogPane().getChildren().add(pane);
          ...
    }

    private void createLeftBox() {
      // Points spinner
      List<Integer> points = Stream.iterate(0, Util::increment)
                                   .limit(MAX_POINTS)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
      this.spPoints = new Spinner<>(observableArrayList(points));

      // Solo combobox
      List<Solotype> soli = Arrays.asList(Solotype.values());
      this.cbSolo = new ComboBox<>(observableArrayList(soli));
      cbSolo.setOnAction(e -> changed());

      // Bock checkbox
      this.chBock = new CheckBox("Bock");

      // Left box
      leftBox = new VBox(spPoints, cbSolo, chBock);
      leftBox.getChildren()
             .forEach(n -> VBox.setMargin(n, INSETS));

      leftBox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #ff0000");
   }

   private void createRightBox(Player[] players) {
      List<Player> playerlist = Arrays.asList(players);
      // Right box
      rightBox = new VBox();
      List<Node> rightChildren = rightBox.getChildren();
      this.playerBoxes = playerlist.stream()
                                   .collect(toMap(p -> p,
                                            p -> new HBox(4)));
      this.players = playerlist.stream()
                               .collect(toMap(p -> p,
                                              this::createToggleGroup));
      playerBoxes.values()
                 .stream()
                 .peek(rightChildren::add)
                 .forEach(b -> VBox.setMargin(b, INSETS));

      rightBox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #ff0000");
   }
```

My class `GameDialog` extends the javafx-class `Dialog<R>`. However the `HBox` in the center of the `BorderPane` doesn't fill all of the available space. It just looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the Dialog]

I tried to setMinWidth, setMinHeight, setPrefSize, setFillWidth(true) and setFillHeight(true) on several of the H- and VBoxes. Nothing Changed. I just don't understand this behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming the `BorderPane` is not as big as you think. Put a visible border to the pane to visualize it

Comment: I added a border to it like:

      pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: #0000ff;"
                    + "-fx-border-width: 4px;");

But that didn't work. I don't see any additional border.
Maybe you're right and it's not the VBox that is small, but the BorderPane. In that case I have still the same Problem: Why doesn't the BorderPane fill all of the available space?

Comment: You don't show the code related to the border pane, so it'll be hard to know

Comment: All of the code that affects the BorderPane is there. It's in the constructor of the Dialog.

Comment: Don't really know what `getDialogPane()`does

Comment: @Dici It doesn't matter what `getDialogPane()` is.

Comment: getDialogPane() is a method of the Dialog-class. It gets the root pane of the dialog-window where all of the nodes can be placed on. It is of the type DialogPane

Comment: @NwDx it does... he's adding his `BorderPane` to the component returned by this method, so the type of layout on this component definitely matters

Comment: @Dici After David's last comment you are right :-)

Comment: Reading the doc of `DialogPane` it should respect the preferred size of its children by default, and since you set the same pref size to the dialog I would expect the border pane to fill the entire dialog. Could you provide a minimal snippet for us to reproduce it ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't fully recreate your example (since some code is missing, I used `TextField` instead of those toggle groups), but had some success with this solution.

Instead of using:

```
getDialogPane().getChildren().add(pane);
```

use:

```
getDialogPane().setContent(pane);
```

And the controls should use all the available space.

---

[image]

(I also removed the setting of the preferred width and height, so the image was a little smaller. Setting the preferred size of the `pane` doesn't change anything any ways.)